# How to install Windows 8.1 using the disk

Tags: windows

I am trying to install windows over ubuntu using the windows 8.1 disk and I literally know nothing about ubuntu. Whenever I put the disk in the computer nothing happens... If I go to archive manager > open > devices I see the disk but when i click on setup.exe it says "and error occurred while loading the archive" How do I open the disk so that I can install windows?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install it while using Ubuntu. Insert the disc,switch off the computer with the disc inside and turn on your computer. Thus you should get to the installation menu of your disc.